# React State remains immutable for states represented with lists

Tags: reactjs

I have a state represented by two arrangements. I must, at certain events, update one of them. The status update function is actually executed, but the status does not change, it remains with the same values before it is invoked. The status update does occur when I refresh the page, but not when the events that invoke the SetState occur.

```
 onUpdateNivel = (pos, level) => {
    this.setState(state => {           
      const listaSensor = state.listaSensor;    
      const list = state.listaNivel.map((item, j) => {
        if (j === pos) {
          return level;
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      });
      var sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + list[i];
      }          
      return {
        list,
        listaSensor,
        sum
      };
    });
  };
```

Comment: Molim te, prevedi naslov na Engleski.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned wrong variable.
Your state has

```
{listaSensor, listaNivel, sum}
```

But when you use setState, the return object is

```
      {
        list,
        listaSensor,
        sum
      }
```

See the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the way the state was returning. The right way is this:

return {
    LevelList: LevelList,
    SensorList: SensorList,
    sum: sum
  };